# SSAS MDX NonEmpty issue

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am having issues when running the query:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Test1] AS
(
SUM({NONEMPTY(EXISTING(([Product].[Product].[All].Children,[Month].[Month].[All].Children])),  [Measures].[Measure1])}, [Measures].[Measure1])
)
SELECT {[Measures].[Test1],[Measure1]} ON 0
([Product].[Product].Children) ON 1
FROM
[CUBE]
WHERE
([Month].[Month].[Jan]:[Month].[Month].[Dec])
```

Based on my limited knowledge of MDX, I assume [Test1] and [Measure1] should return the same results.

Depending on what I put in the where clause (i.e. I change the months) I can get no results for [Test1], even if there are values for [Measure1].

If I change [Measure1] to another measure from the same fact table [Measure2] this problem does not occur.

[Measure1] is just a standard measure, it is not calculated or scoped, etc.
I know NONEMPTY doesn't need to be there and the query works as expected if I remove it, but I would like to know why it seems to filter out non-empty data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gents (and ladies), it looks like this is actually a Microsft Analysis Services Bug.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2606211
I installed the cumulative update and it has resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would remove the `existing`. I see no reason for using it and it may cause the error, according to

> By default, sets are evaluated within the context of the cube that contains the members of the set. The Existing keyword forces a specified set to be evaluated within the current context instead.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145541.aspx)

It seems that your query is executed in another context.

Comment: No point in the NonEmpty either. SUM ignores NULLs. I would use NonEmpty (or Non Empty) for the Rows dimension.

Comment: Existing needs to be there as we are using a third party pivotgrid control that generates MDX and unfortunately it uses subcubes when generating queries.