# mdx nonempty exclude value that exists

Tags: mdx

My understanding of Nonempty() function is that it takes first set expression, apply that onto 2nd set expression and remove ones that do not have value in the 2nd expression.

I have

```
WITH
SET [Date Range] AS
    Filter(
        [Date].[Date].[Date],
        [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value >= CDate(@StartDateParam) AND
        [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value <= CDate(@EndDateParam)
    )

MEMBER [Measures].[DateValue] AS
    [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value

SELECT
{
    [Measures].[DateValue],
    [Measures].[Work Item Count]
} ON COLUMNS,
{
    CrossJoin(
        [Date Range],
        --NonEmpty(
            [Work Item].[System_State].[System_State]
        --  ,[Measures].[Work Item Count]
        --)
    )
} ON ROWS
FROM [Team System]
```

Which returns

```
Date     | State    | DateValue  | WorkItemCount
2/1/2015 | Active   | 2/1/2015.. | 2
2/1/2015 | Resolved | 2/1/2015.. | (null)
2/2/2015 | Active   | 2/2/2015.. | 1
2/2/2015 | Resolved | 2/2/2015.. | 1
2/3/2015 | Active   | 2/3/2015.. | 0
2/3/2015 | Resolved | 2/3/2015.. | 2
```

When I uncomment Nonempty code above,
I get:

```
Date     | State    | DateValue  | WorkItemCount
2/1/2015 | Resolved | 2/1/2015.. | (null)
2/2/2015 | Resolved | 2/2/2015.. | 1
2/3/2015 | Resolved | 2/3/2015.. | 2
```

I was expecting to get:

```
Date     | State    | DateValue  | WorkItemCount
2/1/2015 | Active   | 2/1/2015.. | 2
2/2/2015 | Active   | 2/2/2015.. | 1
2/2/2015 | Resolved | 2/2/2015.. | 1
2/3/2015 | Resolved | 2/3/2015.. | 2
```

What is happening here?

This happens on SQL Server 2014 so the answer in [SSAS MDX NonEmpty issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356044/ssas-mdx-nonempty-issue) doesn't apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to keep things simple.
Just move the `nonEmpty` out a bit:

```
WITH
SET [Date Range] AS
    Filter(
        [Date].[Date].[Date],
        [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value >= CDate(@StartDateParam) AND
        [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value <= CDate(@EndDateParam)
    )

MEMBER [Measures].[DateValue] AS
    [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value

SELECT
{
    [Measures].[DateValue],
    [Measures].[Work Item Count]
} ON COLUMNS,
{
    NonEmpty(
       [Date Range]
       * [Work Item].[System_State].[System_State]
      ,[Measures].[Work Item Count]
      )
} ON ROWS
FROM [Team System]
```

---

**Edit**

@George has posted an interesting approach. He has used a helper measure to then feed into a `HAVING` clause. This clause is fast and should be used whenever possible but I think the overhead of creating a new measure cancels out the performance gain of `HAVING`. Therefore may as well keep it simple and use `NonEmpty`..

I've tested using a simple example similar to a script in this post by Chris Webb in 2006: https://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2006/01/04/the-having-clause/

```
--takes 17 secs
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[hasQuant] AS 
    IIF
    (
      IsEmpty([Measures].[Internet Order Quantity])
     ,0
     ,1
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Order Quantity] ON 0
 ,{
      [Date].[Date].MEMBERS*
      [Product].[Subcategory].MEMBERS*
      [Geography].[Country].MEMBERS*
      [Customer].[Gender].MEMBERS
  } HAVING 
  [Measures].[hasQuant] = 1 ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Whereas just keeping it simple with `NonEmpty`:

```
-- secs 11 secs
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Order Quantity] ON 0
 ,NonEmpty
  (
      [Date].[Date].MEMBERS*
      [Product].[Subcategory].MEMBERS*
      [Geography].[Country].MEMBERS*
      [Customer].[Gender].MEMBERS
   ,[Measures].[Internet Order Quantity]
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NonEmpty()` removes only those crossjoin results that give `null*null`. When you have case like `Resolved*null`, NonEmpty does not work. Also, that approach won't give you best performance. Try this:

```
WITH
SET [Date Range] AS
Filter(
    [Date].[Date].[Date],
    [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value >= CDate(@StartDateParam) AND
    [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value <= CDate(@EndDateParam)
)

MEMBER [Measures].[DateValue] AS
[Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value

// add member to filter out null
// Work Item Count condition 
member hasState as ( iif( ISEMPTY([Measures].[Work Item Count]), 0, 1) )

SELECT
{
   [Measures].[DateValue],
   [Measures].[Work Item Count]
} ON COLUMNS,
{

       [Date Range] *
           [Work Item].[System_State].[System_State].members
 } 
 having [Measures].[hasState] = 1
 ON ROWS
 FROM [Team System]
```

Comment: ...is this performance gain definite? `iif` inside `hasState` will have some overhead. It would be interesting to mock this up against a good sample from `AdvWks`. Maybe replacing `, 0, 1) )` with `, null, 1) )` might further increase speed.

Comment: when is this part of the condition True ? `ISEMPTY([Work Item].[System_State].currentmember.membervalue)`

Comment: When you have null member value, if it is allowed in dimension settings. I commented that you can take it out, rather rare case

Comment: `ISEMPTY([Work Item].[System_State].currentmember.membervalue)` is surely always False so condition is effectively `iif(False AND x..` so always false? i.e. always returning 1?

Comment: To the prev - null instead of 0 will allow use  of NonEmpty, however HAVING should perform better here - you don't need to calculate member twicep. Need to test it out

Comment: @whytheq you are right about IsEmpty, I've rechecked function documentation. I will edit my answer

Comment: I am interested in your idea to create this extra measure to feed into `HAVING` - do you have any references to the use of this technique?

Comment: @whytheq, first found it here https://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2006/01/04/the-having-clause/ read comment by Mosha

Comment: I don't see the relevance. Chris's article and Mosha's comment are talking about the performance gains available in using HAVING. I am talking about your technique of first creating a measure so that you can use HAVING - adding an extra measure especially to use in HAVING isn't something I've seen before. I am testing and will add results to my answer.

Comment: My idea was the same - reduce number of initial calculations / searches(first for nonempty, second for column value). Even if you add new member with IIF function, still better. For most (not every) cases in our cubes it works great, esp when you have huge crossjoin.